# using Federated tables for different data sources

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, federated-table

We are planning to create a standalone MySQL server specifically for Federated tables that points to 4 DB instances.

Sample table:

federated_db1_users
federated_db1_transactions
federated_db2_users
federated_db2_transactions

Is this kind of setup feasible as long term solution? What we are aiming to do is to centralize all of our data set into 1 data source for our reporting tools.

Comment: Use Replication instead of Federation.  Federation has some significant performance issues.

Comment: is this possible to create a replica server on an EC2 instance while master instance is on RDS?

Comment: Suggest you as that question of both EC2 and RDS.